# excel vba userform search

Tags: vba, excel, userform

i need some help with search function with this, how can i convert this that userform will search other sheet of my workbook

name of other sheet is "DataSource"

im planning to separate the data into another sheet of workbook then define a name and i will make it as offset so inshort whenever i put another data it will be able to search with the use of my search userform

This is my code

```
Sub GetData()
Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 3
                UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 2 To 3
            UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If

Else
    ClearForm
End If

End Sub
```

This is my code for editing data

```
Sub EditAdd()

Dim emptyRow As Long

If UserForm1.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 3
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 1 To 3
            Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
        Next j
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

This is defined name of Datasource sheet

Name: data

```
=OFFSET(DataSource!$A:$A,1,0,COUNTA(DataSource!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

Comment: Range objects have a `Find` method. There is seldom any good reason for looping through a range, searching for a value cell by cell.

Comment: i use that code, because im going to search a number like this "205156" like that, whenever i put a number, data corresponds into that number will be automatically populated in other textbox like this

Textbox1: employee No.
Textbox2: will automatically show the name of employee
textbox3: will automatically show the address of employee

Comment: "i use that code, because im going to search a number ..." . This is perfectly consistent with using the `Find` method. VBA isn't the fastest language out there (since it runs in a byte-code interpreter). Something like `Find` is written in C and has direct access to the underlying data structures (rather than having to constantly go through the Excel object model). When searching through large ranges it is noticeably faster. Maybe you don't have time to refactor your code right now, but it is a good idea to become familiar with using `Range(whatever).Find()`.

Comment: i need some help with this one, im having hardtime to set my code to search the offset named sheet, if you can modify the code, that would be a great help for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to go to work soon. Good luck.